# Published ClickOnce app deploying .exe

Tags: wpf, msbuild, clickonce, publishing

I am using MSBuild to publish a WPF click once app. I am calling something to the effect:

```
msbuild /t:publish /p:PublishDir=[some directory] /p:ApplicationVersion=1.2.3.4
```

The output is including the startup WPF project's .exe in the top level directory:

```
\Output\
    \MyApp.exe
    \MyApp.application
    \Application Files\MyApp_1_2_3_4
```

Why is it including MyApp.exe in the output? How can I disable this behavior?

*** additional info ***

I created a brand new test project to reproduce this. Publishing from the project properties does to result with the .exe being copied. But if I publish it from MSBuild it does. Still trying to figure out why MSBuild is including this useless file.

Comment: did you try removing all files from the output folder and republishing?

Comment: Yes, it just keep putting it there on the next deploy.